# What JVM features can reduce the running time of Java applications?

Tags: java

I have heard that the JIT compiler and inline functions are some implementations to reduce the running time of Java applications.

Are there any other ways to use the JVM to reduce the running time of Java applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JIT has many ways to optimize your code. There is a page about it on the [Oracle website](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/perf2.html). There are plently of other articles about Java optimizations, just search the web.

There is also a list of JVM options you can change to tweak the performance of the JVM [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia page for Java Performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance) has a lot of content on it about how the JVM works and is optimized.  There are many linked pages there too, for more information.